# Problema com webview

Tags: android, webview

Estou tentando fazer um aplicativo em Webview, mas quando clico em um botão que contém url ele exibe a se desejo abrir em qual app,  existe alguma forma de fazer o próprio app abrir a próxima página?. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

você tem que setar um WebViewClient no seu webView.

é simples fazer isso, veja:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean overrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

com isso, todos os links serão abertos no aplicativo.